# Rails 3 - generating PDF with barcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, barcode

I'm looking for an efficient way for my rails app to generate PDFs with a barcode and other content. Are there any gems that support this or will I need to build it from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in PDF but you can generate the images and then include them in a PDF render:

http://gbarcode.rubyforge.org/

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4154